# pyodbc: How to store Chinese characters in a SQL database?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I'm trying to store chinese text in a Microsoft SQL database.

My column type is nvarchar. And if I run this query directly in SSMS the results are saved correctly:

```
  insert into xtemp (ind, desp)
  values (1, N'人大花来民北村分社訃実真属葉')
```

But if I try to do it from python code, database just stores it as "????????????"

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

This is my python code:

```
connectionString1 = 'Driver={SQL Server};Server=x.database.windows.net,1433;Database=x;Uid=x;Pwd=x;Connection Timeout=30;Encrypt=yes;CHARSET=UTF8;'
connection1 = pyodbc.connect(connectionString1)
cursor1 = connection1.cursor()

q1 = '''
insert into xtemp (ind, desp)
  values (2, N'人大花来民北村分社訃実真属葉')
'''

cursor1.execute(q1)
connection1.commit()


print("done")
cursor1.close()
connection1.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning of your file, and also change

```
q1 = '''
```

to

```
q1 = u'''
```

This should enable Unicode support in your script and properly encode Chinese characters when sending then to the database engine.

Comment: You're a genius! Thank you so much, Alex.

Comment: If I use `"insert into results values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"` using `pyodbc`, shall I change it into  `"insert into results values (u?, u?, u?, u?, u?);"`